# Can't find Resume File of a candidate when they submitted info using Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, contacts, custom-wordpress-pages, contact-form-7, wordpress-flamingo-plugin

Need some help.
I have the Contact form 7 and the Flamingo plugins on my wordpress site. but when I go to download the file it just says:
"file-cv    7535b29dd0868efd0564b57ec8836b38"

Does anyone know where those files are contained? I checked in Media -> Library and the file is not there.

Looked in Media -> Library.
Looked in "Incoming Messages" under flamingo.

It's not there.